# Comments in mustache.js icanhaz don't work?

Tags: mustache, icanhaz.js

I have the following in my template

```
{{! This is a comment that shouldn't be rendered }}
```

I tried it using the demo here:
http://mustache.github.com/#demo

And found an example from mustache here:
https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/blob/master/examples/comments.html

But comments *are* rendering in my templates.

I'm using iCanHaz 0.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must be some sort of bug with mustache.js - you should report it to them

If instead you try `{{ ! This is a comment that shouldn't be rendered }}`
(notice the extra space), the comment will NOT be rendered